# Spring - Injecting prototype bean within a singleton

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am developing a microservice using spring boot.I am exposing an api "customer" using HTTP method GET. As part of my service layer , I am creating a customer object and populating the customer object using details from an external call. This customer object is returned in the response.

My service layer looks like the below :

```
@Service
Class CustomerServiceImpl{

   public Customer getCustomer(){
       Customer customer = new Customer();
       // populate customer object
       return customer;
   }   

}
```

Instead of using new keyword to create customer , I am exploring if I can inject the bean. I believe I need to create customer object as singleton as each request may need a separate instance. Hence I defined the customer object similar to below in my java configuration class.

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public Customer getCustomer(){
    return new Customer();
}
```

I am injecting the bean this way -

```
@Service
Class CustomerServiceImpl{

   @Autowired
   Customer customer;

   public Customer getCustomer(){
       // populate customer object
       return customer;
   }   

}
```

However in this case , I see the same customer object being returned since CustomerServiceImpl is a singleton. Can you please help with the below questions -

1) Is there a way to create a new customer object for each request inside CustomerServiceImpl by keeping CustomerServiceImpl as singleton?
2) If I go ahead with my current approach , is there a possibility of responses getting mixed up since I always have one instance of customer object? Eg: customer A and B are being fetched in parallel , A starts first , B starts next but completes before A. In this case with request A receive customer B's info?

Comment: The `ObjectFactory` solution in the duplicate is probably the best without any AOP proxying.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis. How does Spring know that it has to create a new object in this scenario?

Comment: It's a prototype. Spring will always create a new instance when requested.

Comment: Thanks - I guess in the example you had referred to ,  a new instance is explicitly being requested via factory.

Comment: Through the `getObject()` invocation, yes.